# using multiple nested if statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nested

Its my understanding that you can stack multiple nested if statements so that you can validate a users input on a form. I have tried to combine two nested if statements so that I can check a users input for multiple fields such as freight and mileage used when they submit but it only goes through the first nested if statement for mileage? Is there a better method to write a script to accomplish this kind of task? The code I have been working with is below. My goal is to have a message alert the user that they have not entered any mileage information for their out of town trip and/or have it alert them they included parts and ask if they ordered them to put the freight info in the freight field. if neither issue exists, I want it to drop out of the if statements and lock the form minus the customer's signature.

```
test = this.getField("City").value;
test1 = test.toUpperCase();

if (test1.indexOf("HOBBS") == -1) {
  if (this.getField("MileageTotal").value === 0) {
    app.alert("You have not listed any mileage for this trip.\n\n Please add mileage information for trips outside of the city.", 3, 0, "Trip Mileage Missing");
    app.alert(this.getField("MileageTotal").value);
  }
} else if (this.getField("TotalParts").value > 0 ){ 
  if(this.getField("Freight").value === 0) {
    result = app.alert("You have indicated that you have used parts on this job. \n Were any of these parts ordered?", 2, 2, "No Freight Entered");
  }
} else {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.numFields; i++){
    var fname = this.getNthFieldName(i);
    this.getField(fname).readonly = true;
  } // makes all fields readonly

  var f = this.getField("TechSigDate");
  f.value = util.printd("mmm/d/yyyy", new Date());
  this.getField("Customer Signature").readonly = false;
  this.getField("LockCustomer").readonly = false;
  this.getField("Lock Form").display = display.hidden;
}
```

I appreciate all of the advice you all are giving. I attempted to combine the statements and use an && instead. This works great for the mileage however it skips the freight validation and goes straight to locking the form. I attempted to set it to be true if TotalParts is grater than 0 and Freight is 0. Am I doing the && statements incorrectly?

```
test = this.getField("City").value;
test1 = test.toUpperCase();
if (test1.indexOf("HOBBS") == -1 && this.getField("MileageTotal").value === 0) {
  app.alert("You have not listed any mileage for this trip.\n\n Please add  mileage information for trips outside of the city.", 3, 0, "Trip Mileage Missing");
  app.alert(this.getField("MileageTotal").value);
}
if (this.getField("TotalParts").value > 0 &&this.getField("Freight").value === 0){
  result = app.alert("You have indicated that you have used parts on this job. \n Were any of these parts ordered?", 2, 2, "No Freight Entered");
} else {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.numFields; i++){
    var fname = this.getNthFieldName(i);
    this.getField(fname).readonly = true;
  } // makes all fields readonly

  var f = this.getField("TechSigDate");
  f.value = util.printd("mmm/d/yyyy", new Date());
  this.getField("Customer Signature").readonly = false;
  this.getField("LockCustomer").readonly = false;
  this.getField("Lock Form").display = display.hidden;
}
```

Comment: If it does not go through the first if-statement, it would indicate, that your value is not 0, and it is not of integer type. I suggest you verify the MileageTotal and Freight values and check if they are of integer type and are set to exactly 0.

Comment: If `test1` contains "HOBBS", then only the mileage condition will be checked, because your other `else`s are part of the outer `if` statement. I'm guessing you need to rethink your nesting.

Comment: I think you don't want nested ifs but combine the conditions with "and" (`&&`). Now if the first condition is true but the inner condition is false the code does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I would always show all problems.

It's annoying to the user to have to fix them all one by one.

```
test = this.getField("City").value;
test1 = test.toUpperCase();

alerts = []
if (test1.indexOf("HOBBS") === -1 && this.getField("MileageTotal").value === 0) {
    alerts.push("You have not listed any mileage for this trip.\n\n Please add mileage information for trips outside of the city.", 3, 0, "Trip Mileage Missing");
    alerts.push(this.getField("MileageTotal").value);
  }
}
if (this.getField("TotalParts").value > 0  && this.getField("Freight").value === 0) {
    alerts.push("You have indicated that you have used parts on this job. \n Were any of these parts ordered?", 2, 2, "No Freight Entered");
  }
}
if (alerts.length === 0) {
  this.numFields.forEach((files, index) => {
    var fname = this.getNthFieldName(index);
    this.getField(fname).readonly = true;
  }) // makes all fields readonly

  var f = this.getField("TechSigDate");
  f.value = util.printd("mmm/d/yyyy", new Date());
  this.getField("Customer Signature").readonly = false;
  this.getField("LockCustomer").readonly = false;
  this.getField("Lock Form").display = display.hidden;
} else {
  // Maybe you can also do alerts.forEach(app.alert)
  alerts.forEach(alert => app.alert)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check both if statements, get rid of the 'else'. This does not appear to be an exclusionary situation, e.g. freight and mileage are possible, yes?

Comment: yes it is possible for both conditions to exist in this form